# Anyone knows this piece with a clip and a pin hole?

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone know what this piece is?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is the so-called [Bad Robot Arm](https://brickset.com/parts/4622904/bad-robot-arm), introduced with the Exo-Force theme but used since then:

[image]